# Fetching old records

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm, transactions

I have written a simple Hibernate program using HQL. 
I had included both SELECT as well as UPDATE into it. When I am updating any records and trying to display it then it returns the old records.
I am committed the transaction after UPDATE but still it fetches the old records.
When I have included a new session for SELECT then it fetch the new records that where updated.  Do I need to create a new Session every time to fetch the latest records?

```
    AppMain.class:
    package com.HQL.Main;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.hibernate.Query;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

    import com.HQL.Model.Employee;

    public class AppMain {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = null;
            List<Employee> list1 = null;

            query = session.createQuery("from Employee");
            list1 = query.list();
            for (Employee emp : list1) {
                System.out.println("\nEmployee ID:\t" + emp.getId() + "\nEmployee name:\t" + emp.getName()
                        + "\nEmployee Age:\t" + emp.getAge() + "\nEmployee Salary:" + emp.getSalary());
            }

            query = session.createQuery("update Employee set age=:empname where id=:eid");
            query.setParameter("empname",36);
            query.setParameter("eid",3);
            int result = query.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Result:"+result);
            tx.commit();

            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Query query1 = session.createQuery("from Employee");
            list1 = query1.list();
            for (Employee emp : list1) {
                System.out.println("\nEmployee ID:\t" + emp.getId() + "\nEmployee name:\t" + emp.getName()
                        + "\nEmployee Age:\t" + emp.getAge() + "\nEmployee Salary:" + emp.getSalary());
            }       
            //tx.commit();
            session.close();
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `session.flush();` and `session.clear();`

Flushing the session forces Hibernate to synchronize the in-memory state of the Session with the database

Clear completely clear the session. It evicts all loaded objects and cancel all pending operations and clear caches for all objects.

After updating try flushing and retrieve like

```
        int result = query.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Result:"+result);
        tx.commit();
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
```

or

Also try with `Session.refresh(Object)`

This should work

More info on https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html

Comment: I have included session.flush() into my code but still it takes the old records while displaying.

Comment: After flush, try using the same session rather beginning another session

Comment: Yes I have used the Session.

Comment: Did you remove this line `session = sessionFactory.openSession();` ?
Did it work?

Comment: ` int result = query.executeUpdate();
tx.commit();

            session.flush();
            Query query1 = session.createQuery("from Employee");
            list1 = query1.list();
            for (Employee emp : list1) {
                System.out.println("\nEmployee ID:\t" + emp.getId() + "\nEmployee name:\t" + emp.getName()
                        + "\nEmployee Age:\t" + emp.getAge() + "\nEmployee Salary:" + emp.getSalary());`
            }

Comment: Yes I had commented the statement earlier "session=sessionFactory.openSession();" and executed the program.

Comment: Are you still seeing the old records ?

Comment: Yes I can still see the old records.:(

Comment: Can you try  `session.flush();
        session.clear();`

Comment: Thanks Prathap. This is working now when I have added session.clear().